# Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct in aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, class

I have the following code which is supposed to take some information from a C# page and display it inside the aspx page, but when I run it i provides me with the error:
"Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct" at line 58 which is this one:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="InboxRecords">
```

Can you please help me and tell me what could cause this problem?

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="InboxRecords">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <% if (inbox == true)
        {%>
        <tr>
            <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Sending")%></td>
            <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "BA")%></td>
            <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Date")%></td>
            <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title")%></td>
            <td><%# if (test != Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DocPath")))
            {%>
                <a href="<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DocPath")%>">Document</a>
            <%}
            %>
            </td>
            <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Subject").ToString().Replace("\n","<br />") %></td>
            <% if (_userTypeId == 1)
            {%>
                <td><a href="Notifications.aspx?Id=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id")%>&delete=1"><img src="img\delete.png" alt="Delete" title="Delete" /></td>
            <%}
            %>
        <%}
        %>
        </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: How you are binding this repeater in code behind?

Comment: I really do not think that you can have if statements in the markup like that

Comment: InboxRecords.DataSource = LoadDocuments(); Where LoadDocuments() is basically a method that contains a select from DB;

InboxRecords.DataBind();

Comment: It looks like you were writing ASP instead of ASP.NET. Why don't you use the codebehind for your logic?

Comment: So you mean to tell me that I should use the C# code behind for those if-statements?